# Kcross inhomogenous function in R

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm trying to compute a Kcross.inhom function for a multiple point patter object with the envelope function in R with the following code

```
envelope_kcross <- envelope(p, 
                        Kcross.inhom, 
                        i = "retail", 
                        j = "culture",
                        nsim = 99)
```

I need it to be weighted on the intensity of the point patters. How can I adjust the code? From what I understood I should specify 'simulate =' but I'm not completely understanding how